# Some space seems to be lost on an ext4 drive on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, data-loss, df

Today I "found" a HDD in one of my systems that I completely forgot I had. So I wanted to look inside and see what was in there. I logged in via ssh from another computer (may be important for the following) and, after quite a bit of fiddling around(*), I managed to mount it and inspect it. It had about 65G of data in it. I copied all what I wanted to preserve and then `rm -rf`ed the rest.

Now `df` tells me that it has a total of 917G, 206M are used and 870G are available. I thought, maybe the files I deleted are not really deleted but moved to a recycle bin. But that wouldn't add up with the shown numbers. I still inspected `'$RECYCLE.BIN'` and `lost+found`, but only in `'$RECYCLE.BIN'` there is a 129 Byte (!!) long .ini file completely unimportant. But I want to make sure there's nothing else important in there before I format it.

Here the questions: does `rm` move files to a recycle bin or does it delete them right away (as I had understood so far)? And if it does move them to a recycle bin, which one does it use when one is connected via ssh?

Where else could I look to see what's taking up that space that `df` can't see?

(*) *just a funny (to me) anecdote: at first I mounted the drive, but `ls` saw it as empty. So I looked with `parted` if I could see anything: the drive had a msdos partition table and it only had partition #2 in it, which was taking up the whole disk. I went ahead and deleted the partition, recreated a partition table as gpt and created a new primary partition as ext4 taking up the whole disk. I mounted it again and, SURPRISE... the disk was no longer empty! I could see a directory, which I then remembered were there to start with, but `ls` couldn't see before I redid the partition. So `parted` warned me several times that all my data would be lost, but it didn't happen. To the contrary I recovered data. Puzzling.*

Comment: By default, a certain percentage of space is reserved for `root` . Also, filesystem structural metadata takes up space. Read `man mkfs`.

Comment: @waltinator I could accept that as explaining the 206M of used space, but between the 917G total and the 870G available there's still a long way to go. 47G of space reserved for `root` (which I wouldn't expect by the way, because it has no operating system on it) or for filesystem metadata seem a little to much to me.